# Set cookie for consent page

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this project below to test my consent overlay page.

The warning page works fine, but does not save your option. So, if you go into the website, navigate trough it and then go back again to home page, you will see the consent overlay again.

Is there any way to save the option using cookies?

[Project](https://consent18.webnode.com/) (**SFW**)

Snippet with consent overlay page code

Thank you in advance!

```js
function openDialog() {
  document.documentElement.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

function closeDialog() {
  document.getElementById("warning").classList.remove("show")
  document.getElementById("warning").classList.add("hide");
}

openDialog();
```

```css
body,
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.consent-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.consent {
  background: #000000;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.consent-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.consent-content h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-indent: .1rem;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 30px 30px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  letter-spacing: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="warning" class="consent-overlay show">
  <div class="consent">
    <div class="consent-content">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OtN0ZEJ.png" width="200" height="200">
      <h1>Este website exibe contéudo explícito!</h1>
      <div class="button">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" onclick="closeDialog(&quot;warning&quot;)">Tenho mais de 18 anos</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="location.href='https://www.webnode.com.br';">Tenho menos de 18 anos</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the cookie or localStorage code? What did you try?

Comment: Well, that's what I need help for..I tried using the javascript cookie set up by w3 school  tutorial but it didn't work out so well.

Comment: "didn't work out so well" is not a valid error. If you had shown your code we might have been able to see why. Now it is just guessing. Please provide enough code to have a [mcve] - It is really too bad that cookies do not work here in a stack snippet but we still want to see the code and possible error messages in the console